# How to select words in a paragraph tag

Tags: javascript, html

Let's say that I have this line in my html file:

```
<p>How can I help you?</p>
```

I want to select only the word that has been clicked on and do something with that word.For example just console.log the clicked word. To achieve that should I have something like this:

```
<p><span>How</span><span>can</span><span>I</span><span>help</span><span>you?</span></p>
```

This way I can use the span tag and select the item but it's not practical at all. Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You better use a class to point clickable spans. Something like `<span class="clickable">can</span>`.

```js
$("p>span").click(function(event){
  console.log($(this).html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><span>How</span> <span>can</span> <span>I</span> <span>help</span> <span>you?</span></p>
```